# Intermittent compile issues on Ubuntu with Java Maven

Tags: java, maven

Some of our devs are running into strange and intermittent Java compile errors with maven. The error
comes in different flavors:

1. Cannot find symbol: id. variable u of type UserData. (UserData inherits the id field from EntityBase in lib-common)
2. Cannot access RoleAssignment, class file for RoleAssignment not found. (this class is in a different package lib-access-control, and is being referenced in the pom.xml and code of lib-user)

[image: Cannot find symbol issue full]

[image: Class file not found issue full]

Most of our devs never run into these issues, but a few hit them every few days. Often times running a 'mvn clean' will resolve the issue, but sometimes even that doesn't work. Often a machine restart is required to resolve the issue.

We are using java version 15, maven version 3.6.0, and Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: Does this apply for a source tree never touched by an ide, but only used with a command line?

Comment: Deleting local maven repository usually helps in such cases.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1744774)

Answer (score 0):

[Maven 3.6.0](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/index.html)  is from 2018. [Java 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_15)  has been released 2020. I'd update to the latest Maven version.